# Is there a name for the opposite reaction to the dissolution?

Tags: terminology

When atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ reacts with water to form $\ce{H2CO3}$, this is called dissolution, isn't it? What term would you use for the opposite reaction when it occurs at atmospheric pressure (e.g. due to temperature change)? For a solid it would be precipitation, but here it is for a gas.

Comment: Good question! But it is maybe worth noting that the process of gaseous carbon dioxide dissolving in water and the reversible reaction of carbon dioxide with water to form carbonic acid are two separate processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Effervescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effervescence) if there are bubbles and

[Degasification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degasification) more generally speaking.

There is also the term [outgassing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outgassing), but that term is broader than just gas coming out of liquid solution.

Comment: thank you for the link. But is effervescence also valid at atmospheric pressure or is it only for high pressure cases (carbonation/effervescence).

Comment: The word can be used at atmospheric pressure, but usually requires bubbles.  If the gas is going to the vapor phase without bubbles I wouldn't use that word.